# How can I find all possible binary representations given the number of 1s?

Tags: pseudocode

Given N as the number of bits and K as the Number of 1s, how can i generate all binary representations that contain K ones and N-k zeros?

in other words i have:

```
N=4 //number of bits
K=2 //number of ones
```

All possible binary values containing N bits,K ones and N-K zeros are:

```
1100
1010
1001    
0110
0101
0011
```

i  have nothing so far. i am not asking for code. i am just asking for the best way to do it? an algorithm? a pseudocode? maybe a discussion?

**Edit: I am asking for code/pseudocode to solve the problem... and not a math formula...**

Comment: does this really have to do with c, c++, and java?

Comment: This is just N choose K,  = n!/((n-k)! * k!) - heh, just realized he wasn't asking for the count.

Comment: ok so how to code such a thing?

Comment: Did anyone read the question?  They're not asking how to find out the number of combinations.  They're asking how to *generate* all the combinations.

Comment: This same question has come up on at least once on SO before - if it weren't about to be closed as "off topic" I'd go and find the dupe(s).

Answer (score 5):

Remember combinations and permutations from math class?

Google it and find the equation, use:
http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html for a quick calculation :)

Comment: *fix* that calculator is a little bogus, but its still that kind of problem.  Sorry about that, I hadn't played with it.

Answer (score 4):

I would say 'recursively' :

Let's say f(K,N) gives you all the possible strings then :

```
def f(K,N):
  if N=0:
    return []
  else if (K=N):
    return [ones(K)]
  else 
    union(concat('1',f(K-1,N-1)), concat('0',(K,N-1)))
```

with:

```
def concat(c,vec):
  retval= []
  for x in vec:
    retval.append(c&x) //& is the concatenation operator
  return retval
```

ones(K) returns a string composed of K "1"

union(x,y) merge the two vectors x and y

Comment: This is great, but its missing an end condition for K:
`function f(N,K){
    if (N==0) return [''];
    if (N==K) return ['1'.repeat(K)];
    if (K==0) return ['0'.repeat(N)];
    return [...(f(N-1,K-1).map((e)=>'1'+e)),...(f(N-1,K).map((e)=>'0'+e))]
}`

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a maths question than anything. You're looking for a string of N length with K of them being 1. So you've got `N choose K`, which is `N!/K!*(N-K)!` if memory serves - *others please correct if I'm wrong!*

Comment: Your formula is close but not quite: `n choose k = n!/[k!*(n-k)!]`.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I should have added in the "*", seeing as this isn't a hand-written form. Added to my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find all subsets of size K of a set of N elements, say `S = {1,2,...,N}`. You can easily express this recursively:

A subset of size K of S is either a subset of size K of `{1,2,...,N-1}`, or it is the union of `{N}` and a subset of size K-1 of `{1,2,...,N-1}`. (This is precisely the recurrence relation for the binomial coefficients.)

Once the subset size is bigger than the ambient set size there are no subsets, so that branch of the recursion stops.

Answer (score 0):

Generate all binaries with N bits.
Check each if the have K zeros and K ones. ?.
Profit.

Comment: generate binaries with 64 bit. where's the profit.

Comment: you don't _need_ to keep them in memory, you can generate one and test. understand the problem first, come up with a solution. make it work. improve it later. POITROAE

Comment: say you need OP's algorithm for 1000 bits. how's your fast?

Comment: Upvote for trying to answer the actual question instead of giving formula for number of combinations/permutations.

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode:

```
loop for every position starting at left, pos=position:
 loop for every position starting at pos+1 -> pos2;
   set 1 at pos and pos2;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Binomial Coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) will give you the total number of solutions.  (See "N Choose K").

Use a [Hamming Weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) to count the number of bits.

```
int main()
{
    int k = 2;
    for(int i = 0;  i < 16; i++)
       if(BitCount(i) == k)
          cout << i << endl;
}

// Got this function from an SO question (see below)
int BitCount(int i)
{
    i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return ((i + (i >> 4) & 0xF0F0F0F) * 0x1010101) >> 24;
}
```

Reference: [How to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)

Answer (score 0):

This is a place to start.  I don't have a compiler on me to test, though.

```
size_t n = 4;
size_t k = 2;

std::vector<bool> bits;

for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
  bits.push_back(i < k ? true : false);

std::sort(bits.begin(), bits.end());

do {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << ( bits[i] ? '1' : '0' );
  cout << endl;
while(std::next_permutation(bits.begin(), bits.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion will be a good solution here given that you memoize the results somehow or for large n & k , the program might blow and you dont print (and go into further recursion) the cases when n=0 OR n0 (only n>=k will be legal states).

Answer (score -1):

This problem is not unusual, and can be difficult to implement, so you'll be happy to find that most languages have some sort of open source solution (or part of the DK) to solve it.

- Java: [Permutations](http://www.merriampark.com/perm.htm) and [Combinations](http://www.merriampark.com/comb.htm)
- Python: [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)

Answer (score -1):

I think you've already got an algorithm there :)

Start by laying out K number of 1's on the left side padding the rest with 0's

Shift the rightmost 1 N-K-1 times to the right, replacing the previous position with a 0 and capturing the result each time

Keep shifting the 1's until they're all on the right side

done.

Answer (score -2):

Each bit can only have 2 possibilities, so just raise your N to power 2.

1. 1 bit, can have two combinations,
2. 2 bit, can have 4 combinations.
3. 3 bit, can have 9 combinations
4. 4 bit, can have 16 combinations

Comment: That doesn't account for the fact that repeats aren't different answers. 1001 would be present multiple times in that set of 16 combinations which means it wouldn't be unique. His question noted the combinations in a set of 4 bits with 2 forced to 1.  I did the same thing wrong at first, that's why I thought the link I provided would work originally :(